# Object variable not set on while clearing contents

Tags: excel, vba

I know I am overlooking a simple and crucial step in my VBA code, so it has gotten to the point where I cannot figure out the syntax of my code. I am setting tabs in one workbook for each month. I simply want to ClearContents of column A and then the rest of my code retrieves the same object error. Any quick ideas on how to resolve this "object variable not set" error and different structure with the rest of the code impacting this error would be helpful? If any more information is need please let me know.

```
Sub copypaste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Jan As Worksheet
Dim Feb As Worksheet
Dim Mar As Worksheet
Dim Apr As Worksheet
Dim May As Worksheet
Dim Jun As Worksheet
Dim Jul As Worksheet
Dim Aug As Worksheet
Dim Sep As Worksheet
Dim Oct As Worksheet
Dim Nov As Worksheet
Dim Dec As Worksheet
Dim Template As Worksheet

Set Jan = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jan")
Set Feb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feb")
Set Mar = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mar")
Set Apr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Apr")
Set May = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("May")
Set Jun = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jun")
Set Jul = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jul")
Set Aug = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aug")
Set Sep = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sep")
Set Oct = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oct")
Set Nov = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nov")
Set Dec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dec")
Set Template = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")


'Clear past SKUs
Jan.Columns("A").ClearContents
Feb.Columns("A").ClearContents   'Object Error here
Mar.Columns("A").ClearContents
Apr.Columns("A").ClearContents
May.Columns("A").ClearContents
Jun.Columns("A").ClearContents
Jul.Columns("A").ClearContents
Aug.Columns("A").ClearContents
Sep.Columns("A").ClearContents
Oct.Columns("A").ClearContents
Nov.Columns("A").ClearContents
Dec.Columns("A").ClearContents

'Copy SKUs
Template.Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Copy

'Paste SKUs on month sheets
Jan.Range("A1").Paste  'Error: Object does not support this property or method
Feb.Range("A1").Paste
Mar.Range("A1").Paste
Apr.Range("A1").Paste
May.Range("A1").Paste
Jun.Range("A1").Paste
Jul.Range("A1").Paste
Aug.Range("A1").Paste
Sep.Range("A1").Paste
Oct.Range("A1").Paste
Nov.Range("A1").Paste
Dec.Range("A1").Paste

'Paste SKUs to template on last row of column
Jan.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Feb.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Mar.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Apr.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

May.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Jun.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Jul.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Aug.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Sep.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Oct.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Nov.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste

Dec.Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy
Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Paste


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I see absolutely no reason for an  "object variable not set" there. In fact, if that call was *not* able to succeed, you should be getting an error on the `Set Feb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feb")` line instead.

Comment: Right? I'm confused on why. Either way I'll keep working on my project and will update this thread.

Comment: Using my original code (I edited some slight tweaks that copied ranges better), the object error now appears when I first try to paste on the month sheets.  Either the solution is something I am missing or the solution is restructuring my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to update the thread, I've condensed my code, so even though I had a lot listed the see the process, the solution itself was just to restructure my code with smarter variables. I used the below code with minor adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but a suggested refactoring to reduce the repetition:

```
Sub copypaste()

    Dim arrMonths, m
    Dim Template As Worksheet


    Set Template = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

    arrMonths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", _
                      "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each m In arrMonths
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(m)
            .Columns("A").ClearContents 'Clear past SKUs
            Template.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Copy .Range("A1") 'Copy SKUs from template
            .Range("A1:C1").End(xlDown).Copy Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        End With
    Next m

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will consolidate!